# How can I use Ajax to check the status and result of a django-celery task?

Tags: python, ajax, django, celery, django-celery

[The Django Celery documentation](http://packages.python.org/django-celery/reference/djcelery.urls.html) suggests there are URLs I can check to get the status of a task. What are these URLs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access these URLs, you need to include them from one of your `urls.py` files. For example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^tasks/', include('djcelery.urls')),
)
```

You would then access them using, for example, `http://example.com/tasks/{{ task_id }}/status/`.

Comment: thanks. If you are familiar with djcelery, can you explain these where the content at these urls is coming from? Are the task statuses written to the djcelery tables in the database? If they are just coming from the rabbitmq server, how long are the tasks registered with there? until the server is restarted? Does that take up memory to store so many task results? thanks again.

Comment: I'd love to answer those questions, and they seem like they would be generally useful. Post them as new questions and link to them here, and I'll answer them there.

Comment: Thanks for the help david. I have created a new SO entry for these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987453/where-is-the-data-provided-by-django-celery-urls-stored-how-long-is-the-data-ava